# Programmatically set the default homepage for Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: c#, .net

I know how to set the default homepage for Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, but i searched Google and Stackoverflow for possible answers on how to achieve this with Mozilla Firefox but with no chances.

I'm wondering if there is a possible way to programmatically set a default Start page for Mozilla Firefox browser using C# ( but i can't figure out where does Firefox store it's homepage.. )

How can i programatically set/change default homepage for Mozilla Firefox ?

Thanyou in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is programmatically edit the prefs.js file in the user profile for Firefox.

It can be found in the directory C:\Users\ [USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ [Some Subfolder]

You will need to add or edit the line that looks like:
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "www.google.com");

Answer (score 1):

I know question was answered but maybe next coders can be need a source.

```
 string firefox = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles");
        if (Directory.Exists(firefox))
        {
            FileInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(firefox).GetDirectories()[0].GetFiles("prefs.js")[0];
            StreamReader sr = di.OpenText();
            RichTextBox rb = new RichTextBox();
            rb.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            string[] s = rb.Lines;
            for (int i = 0; i < rb.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rb.Lines[i].StartsWith("user_pref(\"browser.startup.homepage\""))
                {
                    s[i] = "user_pref(\"browser.startup.homepage\", \"http:\\\\www.somesite.com\");";
                    break;
                }
            }
            File.Delete(di.FullName);
            File.WriteAllLines(di.FullName, s);
        }
```

This will change firefox homepage. I hope I can helped someone

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but I've tried it and it looks like it doesn't work. Any hints ?

Comment: Worked for me. Have you tried stepping through the code, maybe your Firefox prefs are in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use console commands to find the file wich holds your homepage URL

First thing I would try: set your homepage to something non existent to prevent hitting cookies with the same url like www.testfirstnamelastname.com

Then go to your Terminal/commandline
and type

grep -lr "www.testfirstnamelastname.com" *

If you want to search admin protected directories add sudo before the command..

hope this helps you out

Comment: I am working on windows, not linux :) is there a possible way to search for a string within file under windows 7 ?

Comment: Simple: download this program http://www.wingrep.com/ it will help you find reg exp and strings everywhere (this saves alot of time)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link

http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/03/26/add-to-favorite-in-firefox-and-ie/

No need for any code behind.

Comment: @ShikataGaNai C# is a server side language... how do you think that would make a client side change?

Comment: You are using web application or windows form?

Comment: @9ball I am simply trying to develop a file which change the default homepage for mozilla firefox on current computer upon execution.

Comment: @ShikataGaNai my fault. for some reason I assumed web app and not win form. Ravia makes a good point