# How to set default search provider for all browsers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, browser, custom-search-provider

I'm developing a Win Forms application.

I need to set the default search provider for Chrome, IE and Firefox.
Is it possible?

Comment: Here is your answer for Firefox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043616/programmatically-set-the-default-homepage-for-mozilla-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this works entirely different for every browser.

E.g. for IE, it is achieved by editing the registry: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/internet-explorer-tips/change-default-search-engine-ie/